# XCode Issue when compile C code

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-errors

I have a program that make the sum of a and b(readed from file) and write it in a file.The problem come when i compile the code.[image: error]

I have no idea why i get this error because on windows the same code works fine.Thank You.

Comment: Always check if the file opened successfully. ( do an if(in) )

Comment: Are you sure "adurane.in" exists and is readable, so `in` is not NULL?

Comment: Please post the code as text...

Comment: As well as checking the result of `fopen` (XCode is telling you that `in == NULL`) you must check the result of `fscanf`. Both omissions are basic newbie errors. If you had checked them you would not have had to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your use of relative paths is incorrect — Xcode doesn't launch the executable in the folder where the source is (even if it tried to: what should it do when the source is in multiple folders?), so `in` is `NULL` and therefore the `fscanf` has undefined behaviour.

In general, assuming you know the current working directory when launching from an IDE or from a GUI is dodgy.

Comment: So i need to put the entire path to "adunare.in" file ?

Comment: Either that, or make an explicit call to the POSIX method `chdir`, or just take the location of the input as a parameter, as though you were a command-line utility. In Xcode you can click on your project name in the top bar next to the stop button, select 'Edit Scheme...' and use the 'Arguments' tab against the 'Run' target to supply a suitable path and file name. In C you can also use `getcwd` to get the current working directory, should you be curious, but Xcode doesn't guarantee anything so it's probably not a very helpful way to proceed.